# Error Creating S3 Bucket AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio With Admin Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-toolkit

I'm having trouble using the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio to deploy a lambda function.

This is the error I'm getting:
[image]

But I am a global admin and am able to see and access everything through the AWS UI. I think this may be a programmatic access issue, but where do I check or look?

Here are all my current permissions and groups on AWS:
[image]
[image]

How do I successfully use the AWS toolkit for Visual Studio with my admin account (I understand after getting this working, I probably want to back off the permissions - but that's a separate best practice)? One thing I'm certain of is that I'm using the correct `Access key ID` and `Secret access key`, so that itself isn't an issue, sounds like a permissions thing to me.

Thank you!

Comment: What is in your `Force_MFA` policy? How have you provided the credentials (is it just via the `.aws/credentials` file)? Can you create a bucket from the AWS CLI on the same computer (eg `aws s3 mb foo`)?

Comment: Force_MFA seems to be built in, the description says: `This policy allows users to manage their own passwords and MFA devices but nothing else unless they authenticate with MFA`. I provided the credentials through that AWS Toolkit UI, and I checked it looks like it got saved to `.aws/credentials`. I tried `aws s3 ls` through the cli and also got `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: AccesDenied`

Comment: Okay! That was a really good catch. I removed the `Force_MFA` policy and tried `aws s3 ls` and that appeared to work and give me a list of all the buckets. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a policy named `Force_MFA`.

If this policy is requiring users to authenticate with an MFA, then the AWS CLI will not be able correctly authenticate. You would either need to remove this policy, or use `GetSessionToken()` to provide an MFA value and then use the returned credentials with the AWS CLI.